# opening a usb device in python -- what is the path in winXP?

Tags: python, usb

I'm trying to access a usb device through python but I'm unsure how to find the path to it.
The example I'm going from is:
**pipe = open('/dev/input/js0','r')**
In which case this is either a mac or linux path. I don't know how to find the path for windows.

Could someone steer me in the proper direction? I've sifted through the forums but couldn't quite find my answer.

Thanks,
-- Mark

Answer (score 0):

The default USB path on windows is `D:\`. So, if we have a text document named `mydoc.txt`, which is in the folder `myData` the appropriate path is `D:\myData\mydoc.txt`

Comment: It's a joystick, not a hard drive. I guess what I'm trying to ask is if there is a USB equivalent to com ports in windows? Obviously its not on com1, etc. but I'm guessing I need some sort of device address to put into 'pipe=open('whatever path to usb device is', 'r').

Comment: The default USB drive path on Windows is not necessarily `D:\\`. It depends on how many drives & partitions the system has installed as well a whether the device has been permanently assigned a drive letter in the Disk Management snap-in under Administrative Tools | Computer Management.

Comment: @martineau hmmm... good point. I was assuming that only one drive was installed and that the OP had not changed the letter.

Answer (score 0):

"Everything is a file" is one of the core ideas of Unix.  Windows does not share this philosophy and, as far as I know, doesn't provide an equivalent interface.  You're going to have to find a different way.

The first way would to be to continue handling everything at a low level & have your code use a different code path under Windows.  The only real reason to do this is if your goal is to learn about USB programming at a low level.

The other way is to find a library that's already abstracted out the differences between platforms.  PySDL immediately comes to mind (followed by PyGame, which is a higher level wrapper around that) but, as that's a gaming/multimedia library, it might be overkill for what you're doing.  Google tells me that PyUSB exists and appears to just focus on handing USB devices.  PySDL/PyGame have been around a while & are probably more mature so, unless you've got a particular aversion to them, I'd probably stick with them.

Comment: I've seen it done using pygame and have yet to try it but I figured there might be a simpler way. I'll try it that way and give pyUSB a look as well. Thanks for all your help!